# Effective SQL query to find first (by date) associated record in a 1-N relationship

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Here's the scenario: there is a Software table (PK = SoftwareID) and an associated Release table (PK = [SoftwareID,Version]).

A release can be major or minor, release type is identified by Release.ReleaseType ('MAJ', 'MIN').

A release is also characterized by a date: Release.ReleaseDate.

Software is partitioned into categories, identified by Software.CategoryID.

Problem: need an **effective** T-SQL query to list all software pieces of a certain category and having the first major release date falling inside a given interval, delimited by @DateFrom, @DateTo. The only columns needed in the final resultset are SoftwareID and ReleaseDate.

This is not the real case scenario but I formulated it this way to be easier to understand. In the real case the table Release would have around 10 million records and the table Software around 1 million. I came up already with a solution but it's quite slow and I feel the experts around here might find something better.

Here's my slow solution:

```
select  s.SoftwareID, min(r.ReleaseDate)
from
    Software s inner join Release r on (s.SoftwareID = r.SoftwareID)
where s.CategoryID = @Category
      and r.ReleaseType = 'MAJ'
group by
    s.SoftwareID
having
    min(r.ReleaseDate) >= @DateFrom
    and min(r.ReleaseDate) < @DateTo
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is good.

You may want to make sure you have proper indexes for your query:

- in "MSSQL Management Studio": "Query"->"Analyze Query in Database Engine Tuning Advisor", then follow the "white rabbit" (preferred)
- in "MSSQL Management Studio": "Query"->"Include Actual Execution Plan". Then run the query, and look if the execution plan suggests new indexes.

Comment: @Sorin: take a look at solution of Tomalak: he has a very good point with the order of filter/group-by.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an index problem. Have you tried making an index on the ReleaseDate column or creating a clustered index on the table containing ReleaseDate (sorted by ReleaseDate)?

Comment: +1 for suggesting the most likely cullprit but a clustered index on ReleaseDate doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of:

```
select  
  s.SoftwareID, 
  min(r.ReleaseDate)
from
  Software s 
  inner join Release r on s.SoftwareID = r.SoftwareID
where 
  s.CategoryID = @Category
  and r.ReleaseType = 'MAJ'
  and s.ReleaseDate >= @DateFrom
  and s.ReleaseDate < @DateTo
group by
  s.SoftwareID
```

The basic idea is: Why do you filter on a date *after* grouping, when you can prevent unwanted records entering the result *before* grouping takes place.

You are grouping on `s.SoftwareID`. To me it seems that there is no way that `HAVING MIN(s.ReleaseDate) >= ...` would affect different records than `WHERE s.ReleaseDate >= ...`.

Comment: Filter by ReleaseDate in the where clause would bring false positives into the resultset. Most obvious example would be: interval set to a month, software has first major release in the previous month.

Comment: Then what about "WHERE r.ReleaseDate >= ..."? (I'm not sure why you have a ReleaseDate in the Software table at all.)

Comment: There was a mistake in the query, just fixed it.

Comment: Tomalak, i'm not looking for the first major release of a given interval but for softwares having the earliest major release falling into that interval. Billy detailed this in his comments below.

I think the having clause has to stay, unless i'm totally missing something major...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your suggestions. Problem seems to be almost solved, i think there's not much to be done further.

The query advisor suggested 2 useful indexes, one of them being something like:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Release_1234] ON [dbo].[Release] 
(
    [ReleaseType] ASC,
    [SoftwareID] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [ReleaseDate]) WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Index tuning cut the execution time to less than 50%. However, another slight improvement (25-30% of previously halved time) was to reorganize the query by first getting the release dates exclusively from Release table and then joining this subquery with Software:

```
select s.SoftwareID, r.ReleaseDate
from Software s inner join (
    select   SoftwareID, min(ReleaseDate) as ReleaseDate
    from     Release
    where    ReleaseType = 'MAJ'
    group by SoftwareID
    having
        min(ReleaseDate) >= @DateFrom
        and min(ReleaseDate) < @DateTo
) r on (
    s.SoftwareID = r.SoftwareID
)
where
    s.CategoryID = @Category
```

Now I guess index tuning should be redone :)...

Bottom line, use the engine tuning advisor whenever possible and thank you all again.

Comment: Suppose you have dates D1 and D2, and :
software S1 - major releases : R1, R2 in [D1, D2), R3 in [D1, D2), R4, etc
S2 - major releases : R1 in [D1, D2 ), R2 in [D1, D2), R3, R4, etc

What do you want to have as results ?
- S1-R2 and S2-R1 ( earlier major release in interval )
- or only S2-R1 ( first major release in interval )

Comment: Just checking formatting capabilities, coming back soon.

.

.

Comment: Guess I'll have to edit the above response for better formatting :(

Comment: looks like html formatting doesn't work in the comments, see mine above that's pretty messed up :-)